# How to stop an infinite loop safely in JupyterLab?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab, ipython-magic

We are using jupyterLab for some long running operations (doing physic simulations in our case). The user should be able to stop these operations safely without killing the kernel.

Is there a clean ways to do this?

Are there maybe even best practices for this?

---

My cell looks something like this:

```py
environment = gym.make()
running = True
while running:
    environment.step()
    running = ???
serialize(environment)
```

---

#### Notes

- This is not a duplicate of [How to stop the running cell if interupt kernel does not work[...]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750753/how-to-stop-the-running-cell-if-interupt-kernel-does-not-work-in-jupyter-noteboo?rq=1), because I'm looking for a save way to stop **without** interrupting the control flow.
- This is not a duplicate of [How to stop an infinite loop safely in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922909/how-to-stop-an-infinite-loop-safely-in-python), because I'm looking for a way that is suited for JupyterNotebooks and JupyterLab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19040553/, IPython interrupts the kernel by sending a SIGINT. Shouldn't it be possible to catch and handle the signal programmatically, as described in [How to stop an infinite loop safely in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922909/how-to-stop-an-infinite-loop-safely-in-python).

Edit: This sounds helpful: [graceful interrupt of while loop in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280920/graceful-interrupt-of-while-loop-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: if possible I'd like to keep the original signal handler for emergencies, like when I want to stop the cell fast without losing the state of the kernel. That solution does seem efficient though.

Comment: By the way, another interesting option is using a Context manager, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205859/9907994